# How can I remove this redundancy while finding out patterns in a string in R?

Tags: r

I have made a code which does something like this:

It finds all the substrings (of lengths as long as 2 ) in an input string which appear continuously for alteast 3 times.

For eg:

```
    Input             Output
  "110110110"         "110"
  "110110110110"      "110" "101" "011"
  "1010101010101"     "1010" "0101" "10" "01"
```

Now, my code works perfectly and everything seems to be working in the best manner. Now, let us suppose the input string is `1111111111111111`. In this case, the output that I am getting is as follows:  `"11111" "1111"  "111"   "11"` . The output is correct too, but there is a lot of redundancy involved here as you can see for yourself. A pattern (11111) already covers what the next pattern (1111) is trying to give info about.

Any heads up as to how I can handle this redundancy?

Comment: Please provide the code that produces your output and the desired result

Comment: Should I post the code here only or add it as a separate file and upload it?